# Testing the Return Value Within the Finally Block

Tags: c#, try-finally

All, this is a simple one. Is there a way of testing the returned value within a `finally` block without doing

```
bool result = false;
try
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        result = true;
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
finally
{
    if (result)
     // Do something mind-blowing.
}
```

Do I have to use the variable `result` of is there a cleaner way?

*Note: I am aware that this is not a lot of work to do what i am doing now. I am curious for intricacies of the .NET world.*

Comment: Why wouldn't I want to do something like this? To clean up what has happend but insuring it happens after everthing else...

Comment: Well, bad example, maybe : but result will be true only when no error happens. so the `if(result)` in the finally should be in the `if (someCondition)` block...

Comment: Usually finally block is about releasing resources, not a logic. As Raphael said your logic should be in if (someCondition) block.

Comment: With the example you have, result will not be accessible in the finally block.  It is declared in a different context.  You will get a compile error.

Comment: It is a simplification, but I may have multiple embedded try/catches. Here, it is easy to see that I could do it another way, and I appreciate that this may not be the best example, but the question is, can I extract the data being returned `return 'some string[]';` without having to make a copy for example - I can't seem to find anything that suggests you can...

Comment: @Kevin agreed. Edited to reflect this stupidness :].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: No. That is not possible. I'm thinking that you are mostly interested in a good readability for your code.

Sometimes you actually need a reference to other variables in the finally block, even when your function is returning something. 
For example if you're using some IDisposable implementations and you do not want or cannot (in order to preserve readability) use `using` blocks, then you need to `Dispose()` them in the `finally` block.

So, having the extra declaration is not a big deal, especially if it's only one. The code is still readable.

For multiple and nested try/catch statements, a good design decision would be to put each try/catch block with all logic related to it in a separate function which returns true/false or a result that is useful in the caller's context.

Comment: You are exactly right. I often need to call `Dispose` on an `SqlConnection` only if it is open etc. I just thought for readability, if there was a way in the fianlly block to pick up the returned variable with out further declarations etc.

Comment: Well, I guess they could do that with a new language construct. But nothing like that in the CLR implementation yet.

Comment: Be careful what you wish for. Good old delphi, has an implicitly defined result variable. I've seen coders jumping through lots of hoops to use it through the lifetime of a function. It can get just as messy.

Answer (score 1):

Since C# has no equivalent of D's [scope](http://dlang.org/statement.html#ScopeGuardStatement), you are pretty much consigned to `try..finally`.

See also: [D Exception Safety](http://dlang.org/exception-safe.html).

Answer (score 1):

if it was me I'd have an other variable to indicate something was required in the finally block.

You mention SqlConnection in another comment so it could be you do

if (myConnection != null)
{
  myConnection.Dispose();
}

though the pukka .net way would have had the connection in a using block, so finally wouldn't be required to get rid of it.

If you want to stick with result then

```
bool result = false;
try
{     
  if (someCondition)     
  {         
    result = true;         
  }     
} 
finally 
{     
  if (result)      // Do something mind-blowing. 
} 
return result;
```

Would make more sense to me, though perhaps not to others....